# Energy exchanges between a Brownian fluid and particles

Tags: thermodynamics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In the context of the dynamics of polymeric models, and specifically the dumbbell model, one of the forces acting on a dumbbell spring is said to result from "a time smoothed Brownian force" that results from Brownian motion of the surrounding fluid and its action on each of the beads (mid-sized particles). Its expression in its simplest form is given as:
$$
\textbf{F}_b = -k_B T \frac{\partial \log \psi}{\partial \textbf{R}}
$$
where $\psi$ is the density of probability of dumbbell configurations $\textbf{R}$. [1]

Assume there is no macroscopic velocity, then the only two forces on the dumbbell are $\textbf{F}_b$ and the elastic spring force in the dumbbell $\textbf{F}_s = 2k_BT \beta^2 \textbf{R}$, so if $\zeta$ is the drag coefficient,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\zeta\dot{\mathbf{R}} = -2k_BT \beta^2 \textbf{R} -k_B T \frac{\partial \log \psi}{\partial \textbf{R}}
$$
From this I can get the Fokker-Plank equation.

I would like to be able to write the energy dissipation, but this is where I have a problem. If I define the energy of the system b\ased on  the elastic spring potential energy density of the dumbbells:
$$
\rho f = \rho \int_{\mathbf{R} \in R^3} \psi \mathbf{R} \cdot \mathbf{F}_s(\mathbf{R}) d\mathbf{R}
$$
I can work out a term of the energy dissipation in $\mathbf{F}_s^2$ which is clearly positive (and corresponds to the elastic relaxation), but there is another term in $\mathbf{F}_s\cdot\mathbf{F}_b$ which gives a negative dissipation, to be precise, it gives a rate of energy increase equal to $\frac{4\rho (k_BT\beta)^2}{\zeta}$ (and I can even construct initial distributions $\psi$ for which the energy of the system does increase.

I can easily represent that it is natural that there should be an energetic trace of this Brownian force, and I imagine that it is balanced by the heat due to the work of the drag force. But I am unable to write an energy exchange term with the fluid that would correspond to this, or write the energy evolution of the complete system dumbbells+fluid. How can I do either of these?

[1] See e.g Dynamics of polymeric liquids. Volume 2. Kinetic theory, Bird at al, 1987. In Constitutive eqns for Polymer melts and solutions, Larson, 1988, page 43 explains that this expression of the force is such that, at short time scales when "both the spring force and [fluid shear force] are negligible", the velocity distribution of beads will establish to equate the Maxwellian distribution of velocities in the surrounding fluid.

Comment: > *But I am unable to write an energy exchange term with the fluid that would correspond to this* Where would you want to see such term? The energy is supplied to dumbbell by $F_b$ which you already have in the equation...

Comment: @JánLalinský: as I write it, my system has an increasing energy and although I know it is due to $F_b$ I do not know where this energy comes from. So I'd like to have a negative term, presumably coming from exchanges with the "exterior" (ie the fluid), that cancels this energy increase. It can't come for free!

Comment: Where does $F_b$ come from? It is a strange term, I would expect a stochastic force term there, but not derivative of probability distribution(very strange). Whatever mechanism is responsible for this term, is also connected to energy transfer you ask about.

Comment: @JánLalinský: Indeed. It is a term that, it seems, has been postulated by my elders in the 1940s-1980s, see my footnote about what Larson says about it. He cites daunting "Stochastic problems in physics and astronomy" by S Chandrasekhar, 1943 Rev Mod Phys, which indeed shows this pp 20-27 - but afaiu doesn't describe the energy transfer.